# New fields in a table, fill via recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I added a field to a table that already contains data, called "FieldNew" in this example.

Now I try to fill that field with data from a form, in a VBA script.

```
Set rs = .OpenRecordset(...)
rs.Edit
rs.Fieldnew = Field2.value
```

This method works with fields that already contain data, but not with the new, empty one. I also tried

```
rs.Fieldnew = Field2.column(1)
```

since it's a combobox. But I always get error `Error #:3265 - Item not found in this collection`

Does anyone have an idea where this is coming from?

Comment: Field2.Column(1) is an invalid reference, If this is a combo box on a form you need to use Me.YourComboxControlName or if you really want the second column value Me.YourComboxControlName.Column(1) as columns are numbered from 0

Answer (score 0):

It was my own fault, of course. The error was in the line opening the recordset.

Sorry to bother you.